# sass-loader not parsing SASS properly

Tags: css, webpack, sass

I have added the `sass-loader` but it's not actually parsing the sass files properly.

The below styles aren't parsed properly and thus the nested styles doesn't work in the browser.

**_navigation.scss**

```
.el-menu-item {
  float: left;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  color: #909399;

  &.is-active {
    color: #909399 !important;
  }

  .router-link-active {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

However, if I move these nested styles out in the same `_navigation.scss` file... it works.

**_navigation.scss**

```
.el-menu-item {
  float: left;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  color: #909399;
}

.el-menu-item.is-active {
  color: #909399 !important;
}

.router-link-active {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

**My packages**

```
"webpack": "^4.4.1"
"style-loader": "^0.20.3"
"css-loader": "^0.28.11"
"sass-loader": "^6.0.7"
```

**webpack.common.js**

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [{
        loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
    }, {
        loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
    }, {
        loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
    }]
}
```

Comment: Can you show the output when you run your webpack? Did you follow the structure in https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#in-production?

Comment: so it turns out with Vue, you need to add the `lang="sass"` attribute to you `.vue` single file components. Then it all works :) [github issue](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/793)

Comment: Ah yeah. I didn't work with `vue` yet :).

Comment: it's pretty sweet. no more JSX haha